# PIL produce grey pixels in OpenCV image

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a strange output in my images: all the characters are bounded with grey pixels around. I am sure at 90% that is because a OpenCV-PIL conversion issue but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the source image:

[image: src]

And the output (you need to zoom to see the grey pixels..)

[image: out]

A detail here..

[image: out2]

This is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
import tesserocr as tr
from PIL import Image
import os

src = (os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output4\\'))

causali = os.listdir(src)  # CREO LISTA CAUSALI
causali.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

for file in enumerate(causali):  # CONTA NUMERO DI FILE CAUSALE

    cv_img = cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output4\\{}'.format(file[1])), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    # since tesserocr accepts PIL images, converting opencv image to pil
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    # initialize api
    api = tr.PyTessBaseAPI()
    try:
        # set pil image for ocr
        api.SetImage(pil_img)
        # Google tesseract-ocr has a page segmentation method(psm) option for specifying ocr types
        # psm values can be: block of text, single text line, single word, single character etc.
        # api.GetComponentImages method exposes this functionality
        # function returns:
        # image (:class:`PIL.Image`): Image object.
        # bounding box (dict): dict with x, y, w, h keys.
        # block id (int): textline block id (if blockids is ``True``). ``None`` otherwise.
        # paragraph id (int): textline paragraph id within its block (if paraids is True).
        # ``None`` otherwise.
        boxes = api.GetComponentImages(tr.RIL.BLOCK, True)
        # get text
        text = api.GetUTF8Text()
        # iterate over returned list, draw rectangles
        for (im, box, _, _) in boxes:
            x, y, w, h = box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h']

            cv_rect = cv2.rectangle(cv_img, (x-10, y-10), (x + w+10, y + h+10), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=1)

            im.save(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output5\\{}.png').format(file[0]))

    finally:
        api.End()
```

Is there a way to make accept to `api.SetImage()` a opencv variable ?

Thanks

EDIT: Is there a way to delete all grey pixels by giving their color ?

Comment: Are you maybe using JPEG format to store intermediate, pre-processed images? Remember it is lossy which means it does not come back cleanly from disk after you reload it. Consider saving intermediate files as PNG, or PPM format.

Comment: I give as input a PNG and set as output also a PNG. There must be something with PIL library which do this change to JPEG, for sure..

Comment: Error is in im.save...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a binary thresholding algorithm to filter out the "noise" in your image.

[image]

[C++ docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)

[Python docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Comment: Are you sure this works ? The input image is clean, no noise just black and white..
I mean, images are alredy thresholded/cleaned with the previous process before this one.

Comment: I'm not sure 100% what is causing the problem but I am sure this is a viable solution.  It looks like @MarkSetchel [may be on to something](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/blob/master/tesserocr.pyx#L323) concerning the intermediary lossy image formats, as tesserocr will convert to JPEG in some cases.

Comment: It's true, binary it's a way to get rid of grey dots in jpeg images.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is my solution. Found a way to use OpenCV instead of PIL as long as the first one don't convert the image to JPEG during the process.
We will have a clean image from input to output.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import tesserocr as tr
from PIL import Image
import os

cv_img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Link\\Desktop\\0.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

idx = 0

# since tesserocr accepts PIL images, converting opencv image to pil
pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv_img)

# initialize api
api = tr.PyTessBaseAPI()
try:
    # set pil image for ocr
    api.SetImage(pil_img)
    # Google tesseract-ocr has a page segmentation method(psm) option for specifying ocr types
    # psm values can be: block of text, single text line, single word, single character etc.
    # api.GetComponentImages method exposes this functionality
    # function returns:
    # image (:class:`PIL.Image`): Image object.
    # bounding box (dict): dict with x, y, w, h keys.
    # block id (int): textline block id (if blockids is ``True``). ``None`` otherwise.
    # paragraph id (int): textline paragraph id within its block (if paraids is True).
    # ``None`` otherwise.
    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(tr.RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
    # get text
    text = api.GetUTF8Text()
    # iterate over returned list, draw rectangles
    for (im, box, _, _) in boxes:

        x, y, w, h = box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h']

        cv_rect = cv2.rectangle(cv_img, (x-10, y-10), (x + w+10, y + h+10), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=1)

        roi = cv_rect[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\output5\\image.png'), roi)

finally:
    api.End()
```